# How to use jQuery Validator to compare two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate 2 input fields by comparing one to the other and make sure the second is greater than the first.

Do I need to add a custom method or can I just use the variable name in the range method? If so, can you point me to the syntax?

```
var validateSection = function (theForm) {
$(theForm).validate({
    rules: {
        startPoint: {
            required: true,
            range: [0, 100]
        },
        endPoint: {
            required: true,
            range: [startPoint + 1, 100] //Is this possible if I set the function to run on any change to either field?
        },
}
});

if ($(theForm).valid()) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Code with Custom Method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("endGreaterThanBegin", function(value, element) {
    return endPoint > startPoint
}, "* End Point Should be Greater than Start");

var validateSection = function (theForm) {
    $(theForm).validate({
        rules: {
            startPoint: {
                required: true,
                range: [0, 100]
            },
            endPoint: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 100],
                endGreaterThanBegin: true
            },
        }
    });
    if ($(theForm).valid()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Getting $.validator is undefined before I get to form, and then validateSection is not a function when I start testing input fields

Comment: added code trying custom method suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Need to add a [custom validate method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/multiplefields)

Protoype -

```
$.validator.addMethod("endate_greater_startdate", function(value, element) {
    return enddate > startdate
}, "* Enddate should be greater than Startdate");
```

Validation -

```
endate_greater_startdate : true
```

Check for the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hA8M/8/), as different example but will help debug.

Comment: for some reason when I add this I get $.validator is undefined and then when I get to that page and start messing with those fields I get validateSection is not a function. I just added it above the validateSection function is there a special place it needs to go?

Comment: Added a demo link. An example for addmethod.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod('smaller_than', function (value, element, param) {
        return +$(element).val() < +$(param).val();
    });
    $.validator.addMethod('not_smaller_than', function (value, element, param) {
        return +$(element).val() > +$(param).val();
    });
    $('form').validate();
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
    value 1
    <input name="value1"
           data-rule-smaller_than="[name='value2']"
           data-msg-smaller_than="value 1 must be smaller than value 2" /><br/>
    value 2
    <input name="value2"
           data-rule-not_smaller_than="[name='value1']"
           data-msg-not_smaller_than="value 1 must be smaller than value 2"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk8Lvyh1/2/)

Comment: Good Idea. would have been better if had some place to add messages